# Export TFS Workitems to SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to export/Connect TFS (On-Prem) work items to SharePoint online or on-prem list? I need those work Items in SharePoint Task list. Is it possible to set the connection? or another option would be exporting TFS work items on daily basis to Excel sheet and then use that excel sheet synced with SharePoint list? In our organization TFS has been setup on separate server and SharePoint on-prem is on another server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have try below options to export tfs workitems to sharePoint.

1, Connect Your TFS project to Excel first. See the document [Connect Azure DevOps project to Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=open-excel-on-prem#connect-azure-devops-project-to-excel) for detailed information

[image]

After you have connected your TFS project to Excel, Import workitems to excel. You might need to create [custom queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops) to query your workitems in TFS.

[image]

2, After you have imported the workitems to Excel. Go the **Design** tab and Click **Export** to export to share point list.

[image]

You can also export the TFS work items to Excel sheet and upload to sharepoint list.

1, Create queries to query the workitem in TFS and export to csv file

[image]

2, Import workitems csv file to sharepoint via **Import Spreadsheet** web part.

Go to sharepoint-->Click gear icon --> Add an app-->search for Import Spreadsheet

See [this blog](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint/) for more information.

Comment: Hi Levi, Thanks a lot for  your response. Is there a way that I can automate that process?

Comment: You can check out [Microsoft Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/). But i am afraid if it doesnot work for on-premise TFS and sharepoint.